An idea for a continuous nth prime function.
I had a novel idea for a way to generate a continuous version of the $n$th prime function and was wondering if it would work / if anyone could create it or graph it.
The idea is:
Start with the Taylor series $f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p\left(n\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ where $p(n)$ givens the $n$th prime number, it follows that the $k$th derivative at $x=0$ returns $p(k)$.
From this perhaps you can use one of the fractional-derivative formulas applied to $f(x)$ to get the $a$th derivative which in turn gives $p(a)$, where $a$ is any real number.
i.e I want to plot the function $p\left(x\right)=D^{x}f\Big\rvert_{0}$

If we're starting with the Taylor series with $p(n)$ as coefficients, why don't we just read the coefficient next to $x^n$?

@RandyMarsh Because what if I wanted $p(0.5)$ or $p\left(\pi\right)$?
The whole point is to use a fractional-derivative to interpolate between the coefficients.

@SassatelliGiulio I meant nth prime function, my apologies, fixed in the edit.

But why would you want to do that? What information are you expecting at $f(\pi)$?

@RandyMarsh It would be $p\left(\pi\right)$, not $f\left(\pi\right)$, but either way does it matter "why"?
I'm just curious about what results you'd get out of trying to generalize the $n$th prime function to the real numbers.
Isn't that what a lot of math is, impractical curiosity?

The "why" matters because there's infinitely many ways to conjure a continuous $n$-th prime function. We don't have infinite time to consider them all, so we focus on the ones that we expect to give interesting information, either through intuition or through computation. You can, of course, consider whichever function you want, but since you're posting here, I'm assuming that you want to get other people interested in it - and that is hard to do without the "why".

@RandyMarsh I wasn't able to get it working for the prime number function but I was for $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, whose derivatives at zero give $n!$.
When I tried this method it gave me a curve that matched the gamma function.
So the fact it "correctly" interpolated between the integer factorial values is some motivation maybe.
Again though, I was just asking for a graph from someone since I can't get it working myself.

You can plot the partial sums in e.g. WolframAlpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5BSum%5BPrime%5Bn%5D+x%5En+%2F+n%21%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%2C++%7Bx%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D

@RandyMarsh It's the fractional calculus part I'm having trouble with.

So, if I understand correctly, you're looking for a function $f$ such that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=5$, $f(4)=7$, $f(5)=11$, $f(6)=13$, and in general $f(n)$ is the nth prime number, but extend the domain to all real numbers in a "nice" way.  Similar to how the gamma function (shifted by 1) is the extension of factorial?

@Dan Exactly, I simply outline one possible way in my post, not sure if you could consider it "nice" but I thought it was interesting nonetheless.

Your idea doesn't rely on anything special about $p$, right? I.e. it's a general approach for interpolating any function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$.

@Karl Correct, I just thought $p$ was a cool one to do.

It might help to add more to your post about what you did to get the gamma function from the factorial function. The Wikipedia fractional calculus page mentions several different versions of the fractional derivative.

Unfortunately, there is a problem with the definition of $f$ and the domain of most fractional derivatives. Most fractional derivatives depend on another parameter, e.g. ${_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)} \cdot \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f^{\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)}\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha + 1 - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}}\, \operatorname{d}t$ or ${_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}^{\left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}} \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f^{\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)}\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha + 1 - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}}\, \operatorname{d}t$. The parameter influences the domain in which these derivatives are defined (here $x \in \left( a,\, \infty \right)$). If I try every fractional derivative I know, I always get terms that only satisfy $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right) = p\left( n \right)$ outside their domain of definition. More precisely, the lower parameter in the integrals is always $a = 0$, so $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right)$ is undefined since $a = x = 0$. Examples:
\begin{align*}
{_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{p\left( k \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x^{k - \alpha} - a^{k - \alpha} \right) \right]\\
{_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{p\left( k \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x^{k - \alpha} - a^{k - \alpha} \right) \right]\\
\end{align*}
These are obviously only true for $a = 0$, so $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( x \right) \wedge x = 0$ is not defined. This is a somewhat unsatisfactory answer, so I want to try other alternative formulas (e.g. a Taylor series around $x = b$ and of several variables). Unfortunately, these lead to the same problems, since ${_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ x^{k} \right] = \theta\left( k - \alpha \right) \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x^{k - \alpha} - a^{k - \alpha} \right) \wedge {_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ x^{k} \right] = \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x^{k - \alpha} - a^{k - \alpha} \right)$, which makes $\frac{\operatorname{d}^{\alpha_{1} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}}f}{\operatorname{d}x^{\alpha_{1} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}}}\left( x_{1},\, \ldots,\, x_{n} \right) = g\left( \alpha_{1},\, \ldots,\, \alpha_{n} \right)$  only true for $a_{1} = x_{1},\, \ldots,\, a_{n} = x_{n}$ (where $a_{\cdot}$ is a index of the derivative), and thus ${_{a_{1},\, \ldots,\, a_{1}}\operatorname{D}}^{\alpha_{1},\, \ldots,\, \alpha_{n}}\left[ f \right]\left( x_{1},\, \ldots,\, x_{n} \right)$ is undefined.
